# Docker add all folder files to the existed folder without replacement

Tags: docker, dockerfile

How to copy folder files into docker existed folder without file **replacement**

```
Example:

locally
|-- demo
|   -- file3.txt
|   -- file4.txt

docker
|-- app
|   -- src
|      -- file1.txt
|      -- file2.txt
```

It can be done via `RUN COPY demo/file3.txt app/src/file3.txt` but it's not a great way to workaround it if there are multiple of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) command should work, no need to specify full path along with the filename while copying.

Here is an example where I want to copy all the files inside `demo` folder onto `/app/src` folder of the container.

```
/ # [node1] (local) root@192.168.0.23 ~
$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM alpine
RUN mkdir -p /app/src
RUN touch /app/src/file1.txt
RUN touch /app/src/file2.txt
COPY demo/* /app/src/
[node1] (local) root@192.168.0.23 ~
$ ls demo/
file3.txt   file4.txt   fileabc.sh  filexyz.py
[node1] (local) root@192.168.0.23 ~
$ docker build -t myimage:v1 .
$
[node1] (local) root@192.168.0.23 ~
$ docker run -it --rm myimage:v1 ls -ltrh /app/src/
total 0      
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           0 Aug 17 11:40 file3.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           0 Aug 17 11:40 file4.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           0 Aug 17 11:40 file1.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           0 Aug 17 11:40 file2.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           0 Aug 17 11:47 filexyz.py
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           0 Aug 17 11:47 fileabc.sh
[node1] (local) root@192.168.0.23 ~
$
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes, it works. But is possible to copy folders? Right now all files inside folders copied without folders by itself. In other words to have folder hierarchy

Comment: Yes you can copy folder to `COPY demo /app/src/demo`

Comment: I want to copy demo files including folder hierarchy to src files and not replace them as you wrote in your answer it works without replacement